# magento minicart add subtotal in icon area where count is shown

Tags: mini-cart

Seems like a pretty simple task but I've edited **minicart.phtml** with `<span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>` 
 and can't seem to figure out why I can't get subtotal next to the shopping cart icon and item count in the upper right hand area.

[image]

What is the file that needs to be edited?

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

or it is in prepossessed ?

Comment: Files that live in preprocessed are disposable. Any effort spent on those files will be lost. Same with pub/static

Comment: @ShawnAbramson noted* I had a feeling that was the case with those folders. When you deploy static content it gets moved to those folders as a cached version or something to process content/data faster or something?

Comment: Thats correct. Magento goes through all installed modules and themes and sorts files in terms of the fallback order. Ultimately, they end up in pub/static. Anything inside of the entire var folder is disposable, not just the view_preprocessed. Also pub/static of course.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson Thanks for clarification, getting a bit off topic now but if i was to rm -rf pub/* var/* it would just rebuild afterwards? For instance I've been wondering if i could delete that off my master and then push to github/bitbucket so it's gone from my repo and then add it to my .gitignore ... assuming it's just going to rebuild everything inside those folders and then my .gitignore would just ignore like it's suppose to?

Comment: Ok, there are several parts to this answer, you might be best off asking an official question and I can type up a full explanation. If you are in developer mode, it will rebuild automatically. If you are in production mode, you will need to `php bin/magento set:static-content:deploy` and then `php bin/magento cache:flush`. The var folder actually should not be in your repo to start with, with the exception of the .htaccess file that lives within it. Most, but not all, of pub, should be excluded too. Take a look at the .gitignore file included in your Magento install.

Comment: You can do something like `git rm -rf --cached var/view_preprocessed`, and so on for each of the sub folders. Just leave .htaccess committed. This will remove it from tracking on git. Be sure to add the deleted files to your .gitignore file if they are not already there,.

Comment: I'm not using any .htaccess nor apache.

Comment: Even better. It would not hurt to keep it but it sounds like there will be no harm if you delete it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76863/discussion-between-supplement-and-shawn-abramson).